# Trying to get base url with reg ex

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I need to match the "base" url, what I mean is:

```
Not match --> http://google.com
Not match --> http://www.google.com
Not match --> www.google.com
Match! --> google.com
```

I was trying to use a negative look behind to make sure there was no http:// or www, but it didn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Does it need to be in one regex? What regex did you try?

Comment: You might want to look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). A regex solution for this can get very messy.

Comment: `google.com` as a url means something completely different than `http://google.com`. "base domain" might be a better term than the thoroughly incorrect "base url".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do this has to be with only one regex?**

You could have the first regex that will match all URLs found. Something like that:

```
\b.+?\.\w{2,4}\b
```

And then filter all matches and keep the ones that do not match the following:

```
^(http://|www)
```

although to be honest, I wouldn't use Regex unless it is strictly necessary for that.

**Note:**
You can always find a better regex to match the URLs. The thing here is that they may not start with `http://` or `www`, so we can't restrict the regex so much. Be ready to have other matches that are not urls at all, like:

`yesterday.but` in `I was there yesterday.but no one saw me`

Comment: I agree, I already thought of them not starting with http:// or www and thought I'd figure something out but you are right.  As it is a simple "enter URL field", I guess each URL will have to be reg ex, and than manually looked at.  Thanks

Comment: If that's going to be a text field just for the url, you can do some other validations (see if contain spaces, etc), and replace `\b` by `^` and `$`. You can read the guidelines of which characters are accepted in urls.